# how to force values with attr library in python?

Tags: python, class, attr

i am new to the attr library and I am trying to implement the following. I want the class attribute x to be without any user defined default values, and I want the class attribute parameter to have a default value True. and when I call the class to change the default value.
Somehow I cannot do that because the calling requires x
(error is : **init**() missing 1 required positional argument: 'x')
Am I missing something basic here?
Thanks for pointing me in the right direction

```
import attr

@attr.s(auto_attribs=True)
class Point:

    x: float
    parameter: bool = attr.ib(default= True)
    print("parameter:   ", parameter)


point = Point(parameter=False)
```

Comment: You need to provide a value for `x` when you create a `Point` as it doesn't have a default value. It has to be assigned *something*.

Comment: i thought floats can be assigned automatically 0.0 by the compiler